# Magento href returns to same page

Tags: php, magento

I have the following in my homepage (changed via page at backend):

```
<div id="pr1" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.example.com/armados/';"></div>
```

It correctly displays the div, however after clicking it, the page returns to just www.example.com

I can acces the page correctly if I just type it in the url bar.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check setting in either .htccess file or URL rewritting using Catalog > URL Rewrite Management and then System > Index Management and select the Catalog Url Rewrites to refresh them

Comment: Thanks, in htaccess:
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

############################################

Comment: I did trid and checked what Joe suggsted, however found that the culcript was an incorrect link.

Instead www.example.com I needed just example.com